# No top bar or menu on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, mobile-web, top-bar

The mobile site of Careers does not have a black top bar or a menu. You need to go to the full site to access your messages, your profile, etc.

When opening the messages page and switching back to mobile, it looks OK apart from some visual bugs.

Is the lack of a top bar on purpose, or is it a bug?

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: I never noticed Careers have a mobile view. *goes looking*. Nope, nothing. How you reach the mobile view? Can't see "mobile" link anywhere. :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard you can only see the link to switch between mobile/full when you're actually using a mobile device, it seems. (Or you could emulate one via your browser's dev tools). The link appears at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, saw it now and took the liberty to add screenshot to make it clear how it looks like. I assume it's by design, but agree it's way too minimal - no way to see your profile or know what user you are logged in with.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The pages available from the top bar (profile, messaging, ...) don't currently have mobile versions. That's why the top bar is absent from the mobile site.

The top bar works well in a desktop environment, but a slightly different UI would be required on mobile.

There are currently no plans to implement these new views or a top bar equivalent on mobile (though that might change in the future.)